# rotate if the image completely rotated

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am currently using [jQuery animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to rotate an image. Here is my code:

```
var wheel = $('#wheel');
wheel.on('click', function() {
    var angle = 500;

    $(wheel).animate({}, {
        start: function() {
            if (!isSpin) {
                console.log('Start spinning');
                wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
                isSpin = true;
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Finish spinning');
            isSpin = false;
        }
    });
});
```

I want to rotate image if the image finish rotated, but it's seems the code inside complete function not working as expect, it running while the image still rotating. How can I detect if the image finish rotate?

Answer (score 0):

Run The transformation in a `loop`.

```js
function AnimateRotate(angle,repeat) {
    var duration= 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(repeat && repeat == "infinite") {
            AnimateRotate(angle,repeat);
        } else if ( repeat && repeat > 1) {
            AnimateRotate(angle, repeat-1);
        }
    },duration)    
    var $elem = $('#wheel');

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now) {
            $elem.css({
                'transform': 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'
            });
        }
    });
}

var wheel = $('#wheel');
wheel.on('click', function() {
  AnimateRotate(360,"infinite");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="wheel" src="https://opensource.org/files/google.png">
```

Comment: I mean when the image is rotating, the onclick event not effect, only when the image finish rotate.